# ¿Cómo deshabilitar options por medio de una clase?

Tags: javascript, html

He creado una función para intentar deshabilitar **options** de ciertos **selects**; solo que no logro hacerlo. Esta función si me trae los **options** que necesito deshabilitar, pero a la hora de asignarles `disabled` a los elementos no ocurre nada.

```js
const desabledFields = (clase) => {
  let campos = [...document.getElementsByClassName(clase)];
  campos = campos.filter((elem) => elem.type == "select-one");
  campos.forEach((campo) => {
    [...campo.options].forEach((option) => (option.disabled = true));
  });
  jQuery(`.${clase}`).prop("readonly", true);
};

jQuery(document).ready(() => {
  desabledFields("read");
});
```

Comment: Agrega el HTML por favor

Comment: A tu ```getElementsByClassName(clase)``` le falta ' ' o sea ```getElementsByClassName('clase') pero como dijo BetaM por favor agregar tu html. Tambien agrega si te tira algun error o algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//el primer campo no va a desactivar porque tiene la clase diferente.
const desactivarCampos = () => {
  // obtenes todos los campos que tengan la clase texto
  let campos = document.getElementsByClassName('texto')
  // si imprimis campos te muestra que tenes un objeto de key value.
  // console.log(campos)
  // recorres tu objeto y le agregas disabled.
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(campos)) {
    //console.log(`${key}: ${value.value}`);
    value.setAttribute('disabled', 'true')
  }
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    desactivarCampos()
});
```

```css
.texto{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="texto-sin-desactivar" >
<input type="text" class="texto" >
<input type="text" class="texto" >
<input type="text" class="texto" >
<input type="text" class="texto" >
```

Espero que te sirva de guia. Saludos.